# Join Only Rows that Match A Certain Condition SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables: `A` and `B`

`B` has a foreign key to `A` and `B` has a `timestamp` field.

`A` also has a `timestamp` field. I am interested in the difference between their timestamp fields for rows in `A` and the corresponding row in `B` with the earliest time stamp. How do I compute this value for every row in A?

For Example:

A row in `A` might have 5 rows in `B` with (5/1/2015, 2/3/2014, 2/3/2013). I am only interested in the time difference with the row with `timestamp` of 2/3/2013.

We can do a join for each entry and slowly build up a table but that does not seem like the correct approach.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I am using the SQLAlchemy ORM.

Comment: I think the answer of @PhilipDevine is essentially a solution, you just need to translate it to `sqlalchemy`. If you need help with that, please post the code you already have tried, since it would depend on how you've built the tables A and B, the relation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Where b.timestamp = (select min(timestamp) from B. X where x.id = b.id)
```

This will give you the min timestamp for that record.